# Semantic UI adding class dynamically to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

It seems there is an issue with adding class dynamically to input field in SUI.

My goal is to active a disabled input on double click, then disabled it again on blur.

On https://jsfiddle.net/Greggg/e1x7jnor/2/ on first input I am adding css dynamically with success. On second input, I am trying to do the same just by adding class and it does not work.

Here is code

```
<div class="column">
  <div class="ui disabled transparent test2 input">
  <input value="Add class do not work" type="text">
</div>
```

```
$(".disabled.transparent.test2").dblclick(function() {
  $(this).addClass('focus').removeClass('disabled transparent');    
  $(this).find('input[type=text]').addClass('active');
});
```

Is it a SUI issue or a miscoding?

Any help would be appreciated

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is getting added, but the background color is getting overriden by another rule because of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Also since the class `active` is dynamically added, you need to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) to target those elements.

```js
/* Focus on double click on page name */
$(".disabled.transparent.test1").dblclick(function() {
  $(this).addClass('focus').removeClass('disabled transparent');
  $(this).find('input[type=text]').css('background-color', 'red');
});

$(".disabled.transparent.test2").dblclick(function() {
  console.log('a')
  $(this).addClass('focus').removeClass('disabled transparent');
  $(this).find('input[type=text]').addClass('active');
});

$('.ui.input').on('blur', '.active', function() {
  alert("test");
  $('input').hasClass('.active').addClass('disabled transparent');
});
```

```css
.ui.input input.active,
.ui.input.focus input.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <div class="ui disabled transparent test1 input">
    <input value="Add css work" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="ui disabled transparent test2 input">
    <input value="Add class do not work" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```